# Firestore security rules: update disabled but update perfectly

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My firebase project has connected with two flutter projects. I want to disable to update using

```
/Order/{uniqueCode} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if true;
        allow update: if false;
        allow delete: if false;
    }
```

but both from my flutter app if I run this query

```
firestore!.collection('Order').doc(order!.orderId!).update({
                                            'payment': true,
                                            'paymentFrom': 1,
                                            'status': 2,
                                            'paymentDate': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                                          }).then((_) {
                                            print('update successfully');
                                          }).catchError((onError) {
                                            print(onError.toString());
                                          });
```

the fields is updated properly

Comment: I *suspect* that having `allow write` basically allows *every* write operation. I would suggest removing `allow write` and instead specify each granular operation separately - so false for update/date, but `allow create: if true;`

Comment: i need to disable the update operation @JonSkeet

Comment: Yes, I know. And I'm saying that I suspect having `allow write: if true;` is stopping you from doing that. So remove that line, and add `allow create: if true;`. Leave the rest the same. I don't *know* that it'll work (otherwise I'd have added it as an answer), but I *suspect* it will. It's at least worth trying.

Comment: I can confirm this is true - this falls under granular conditions available in Security Rules, by default, all values are false until defined by conditions.

Comment: A write rule can be broken into create, update, and delete. You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations)

Answer (score 0):

If you try playing with the rules in the Rules Playground, it's the `allow write: true` that's allowing the update operation:

[image]

You can read more about [granular operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations). Create, update, and delete are all 'write' operations.